# 2 PHP conditions of Find and Append

Tags: php

I have written a PHP code that fetches website images from my other website (both are on separate hosting)

```
$listings['pic'][$count] = $critem[2];
```

The `$critem[2]` sometimes returns either 1 or 2

```
1. https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/featured-content-gallery/scripts/mootools.v1.11.js

2. /wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Sidetracks-Main-1.jpg
```

What I am trying to do is Find

`http://www.example.com` and replace with `https://www.example.com`
    and if there is no domain in the `$critem[2]` as in the (2nd example) append `https://www.example.com` to the string

I am stuck as `str_replace`does not work in this criteria

Comment: So you want it to look like: `<img src="http://www.example.com=/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/45432.jpg"` ?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone should look like <img src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/4543‌​2.jpg"

Comment: @LawrenceCherone https://

Comment: Can you fix your question then...

Comment: `str_replace('src="/', 'src="'.$url.'/', $src)` would work

Comment: Since `wp-content` is common starting point, why not remove everything before that and add `https://www.example.com` in the starting.

Comment: @Sidharth using str_replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$arr = ["http://www.example.com//wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Sidetracks-Main-1.jpg", "/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/45432.jpg", "/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/39223.jpg"];

foreach($arr as &$link){
    $link = str_replace("http://", "https://", $link);
    if(substr($link,0,8) != "https://") $link = "https://www.example.com" . $link;
}

Var_dump($arr);
```

It replaces http with https if it's in the string.
And if the link does not have the http, it adds it with the str_replace
https://3v4l.org/G0AiQ

Comment: I tried your solution but it is not adding the https url when <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/39223.jpg" alt="Spectacular Delaware Riverfront Acreage ">

Comment: so first condition works change from HTTP to HTTPS, but second doesn't

Comment: What are you supposed to get on the second string then? I thought it was add https. Post your expected results on both strings in your question. https://3v4l.org/4Z28g

Comment: Sorry my bad I updated the question there is no IMG or src tag so it is a normal string, please help!

Comment: This is not working if(!strpos($critem[2], "http://")) $critem[2] = str_replace('"/wp', 'https://www.example.com/wp', $critem[2]);